# Rails link_to the records of a instance variable .count() result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, render, link-to

I have records in my **Submitter model** being shown in **Application Index view** being displayed in a table like below. Only I want to be able to click on the number that's listed for the `.count()` and be taken to my **Tickets Index view** with all of the corresponding records (Tickets) listed.

I'm having trouble understanding how I can link instance variables to a controller's action, in order to use the layout of my views.

Any ideas?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number of Tickets</th>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <% Submitter.where(:school_id => current_user.school_id, :disabled => false).each do |sub| %>
    <td><%= link_to sub.full_name, edit_submitter_path(sub) %></td>
    <td><%= Ticket.where(:submitter_id => sub).count %></td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :feedbacks
resources :products

get "password_resets/new"
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

resources :users
resources :sessions
resources :password_resets
resources :mailing_lists
resources :submitters
resources :emails
resources :notes
resources :reminders
resources :descriptions
resources :issues
resources :locations
resources :schools
resources :tickets

root :to => "application#index"
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a submitter that has many tickets. If so, you'd show a list of submitters (in the submitters_controller#index method) and count the number of tickets.  Then link that number to the tickets_controller#index method.  Like this...

routes.rb

```
resources :submitters do
  resources :tickets
end
```

submitters_controller.rb

```
class SubmittersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @submitters = Submitter.where(:school_id => current_user.school_id, :disabled => false)
  end

end
```

tickets_controller.rb

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @submitter = Submitter.find(params[:submitter_id])
    @tickets = @submitter.tickets
  end

end
```

views/submitters/index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number of Tickets</th>
  </th>
  <% @submitters.each do |sub| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to sub.full_name, edit_submitter_path(sub) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to pluralize(sub.tickets.count, 'ticket'), submitter_tickets_path(sub) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

views/tickets/index.html.erb

```
# This would show a list of tickets and their attributes - possibly linking to a ticket.
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm showing the list of Submitters and Ticket Numbers in my Application Index, and then linking them to the Ticket Index. I feel like that changes things from what you have.

Comment: It is a tiny change, but worthwhile.  If you are showing a list of submitters, that should go in the submitters_controller.  This is what the index does.  It's restful, and worthwhile to follow this pattern.  Rails encourages you to do so, and you'll find your project will develop more smoothly if you follow rails conventions.  You should be able to cut and paste your index method from the application controller, then link to the /submitters url.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. My reasoning is more because of a design aspect than a functional. However, to test I set it up like you did and it seems like its going to work and loads a /submitter/{submitter_id}/tickets URL, but only shows my regular index page. I'm guessing because I already had a @tickets before. `@tickets = paginate.where(:school_id => @current_user.school_id).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).search(params[:search])` How can I get it use a different action or instance variable?

Comment: Ah - Yes, in this case, where you want to use the same action for /tickets and /submitter/:submitter_id/tickets, you have to look for the submitter_id param and instantiate @tickets conditionally. A simple if param[:submitter_id] will do.  If submitter_id is on the ticket record, you can add it to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? Not 100% understanding your question.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number of Tickets</th>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <% Submitter.where(:school_id => current_user.school_id, :disabled => false).each do |sub| %>
      <td><%= link_to sub.full_name, edit_submitter_path(sub) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to pluralize(sub.tickets.count, 'ticket'), tickets_path %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I, of course, can't give you perfectly working code unless I know what your `config/routes.rb` looks like, since I don't know what is the method for your **Tickets Index view**.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. Not sure how to word it. This is sort of the right direction. However, this when I click these, it loads localhost:3000/tickets.*insert_random_number_here* which is obviously just a blank page. My **config/routes.rb** is standard. To explain further, if the count() returns 4. I'd liek to click on the number 4 and be shown those 4 records.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your `config/routes.rb` is standard, since I don't know what should be in it. Does `ticket_path` need to be passed the subscriber or not?

Comment: You can make both of our lives easier by posting your routes :)

Comment: I realized the  localhost:3000/tickets.*insert_random_number_here* is actually the submitter Id, not a random number.